# Append new line in all files of the folder

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I have 300 files in a folder. I have to append one new line at the end of all files in a folder.

How can i achieve it using grep.

I tried the following command but its not working

```
sed 's/$/\n/' /Path/filename.txt
```

Comment: That sed command will replace the end of every line with a newline (should double-space the file). `$` is the last line in the file when used as an address (e.g. outside of the `s///` command). So `$s/$/\n/` would match the last line in the file.

Comment: @EtanReisner I tried the modified code like below sed '$s/$/\n/' /Path/*.txt. It creating a new file in the name *.txt and it creates a empty line there. I want to append the new line to my existing files in that folder

Comment: That command could not possibly have created a new file. `sed -i '$s/$/\n/' /Path/*.txt` should work correctly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just say `echo "" >> file`. This will append a new line at the end of `file`.

To do it in all the files in the folder:

```
for file in *
do
    echo "" >> "$file"
done
```

From the comments, in your case you have to say:

```
for file in /path/*.txt
do
    echo "" >> "$file"
done
```

Comment: If you want to loop through directories recursively, you can change /* to  /**/*.txt